# Trying to implement a default base class in javascript not sure its correct

Tags: javascript, inheritance, backbone.js, underscore.js, base-class

I come from a C++/Java background, but I'm having problems getting the syntax right on this javascript. This is what I was trying to accomplish. I want a base class TemplateBaseView which inherits from Backbone.View. The TemplateBaseView overrides the initialize and render function from the Backbone.View. I am also using underscore.js. Here is a brief attempts, any help would be appreciated.

```
  function TemplateBase(){}
  TemplateBase.prototype.render = function(){ ... }
  TemplateBase.prototype.initialize = function(){ ... }
  _.extend( TemplateBase , Backbone.View );
```

And I essentially want to do something like this,

```
var HeaderView = TemplateBase({ template: _.template($("#header_template").html())};
```

which would create a Backbone.View object essentially with the default render and initialize function and the template attribute specified.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the built in `extend` from backbone.

```
var TemplateBase = Backbone.View.extend({
  'this': 'is',
  'a': 'class'
});

var HeaderView = new TemplateBase;
```

A couple things.  You can refer to TemplateBase as a 'class' but there's really no such thing in javascript, that's just a useful name for people coming from class based languages.  It's technically a prototype.

Next:  Remember to use `new` when you create an instance of TemplateBase, otherwise you're just invoking a function and setting your object to whatever that function returns, rather than an instance of that prototype.

Finally, just a convention, most people would capitalize their 'classes' but not their instances.  So I could change `HeaderView` to `headerView`

*edit*

After reading your question again, maybe you want `HeaderView` to be a class?  In which case:

```
var HeaderView = TemplateView.extend({
  template: _.template( $("#header_template").html())
});

var headerInstance = new HeaderView;
```